# Conditional Operation

Tags: c, module, conditional-statements

If I have a function such as

```
f1 (int a)
{
   a = a % 2 ? a + 2 : a;
   printf(”%c ” , ’a’ + a);
}
```

and I call f1(0)
What does a%2 as the condition mean?

Comment: `%` = Modulus Operator and remainder of after an integer division. `a = a % 2 ? a + 2 : a ;` expands to a = if a / 2 has reminder, then a+2 else a`

Comment: Why does your code have weird spacing?  Or, I should say, why does your code have `w e i r d  s p a c i n g` ?

Comment: also the weird quotes `”` looks like word with auto spellcheck enabled  is used for code editing.

Answer (score 1):

It checks whether `a` is even or odd.

`a % 2` gives remainder after dividing `a` by `2`, i.e. `0` for even numbers and `1` for odd numbers. And then `0` or `1` is used as condition expression in ternary operator `?:` to use either the first expression or the second expression as the final expression result.